# Join 5 tables in My SQL oracle

Tags: mysql, sql

individuals:

```
IndividualID (PK)
GroupID*
First name
Surname
Gender
DOB
Emergency contact
Home add
Tel
```

Activity group:

```
ActivityGroupID (PK)
ActivityID*
Individual ID*
```

Activity:

```
Activity ID* (PK)
SessionID* (PK)
Activity description
```

Sessions:

```
SessionID (PK)
Activity ID*
Dates
Type (morning/afternoon) Supervisor ID*
```

Activity supervisor:

```
Supervisor ID (PK)
Name
Mobile number
Comments
```

This is a copy and paste of my current tables (I put (PK) for primary key because underline did not come through), the question is to:

> "query that gives full details of all the activities in which an individual member has taken part, including the  name of the activity supervisor in each case."

I'm fairly new to MySQL and any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far. Stack Overflow isn't a code or query-writing service. Give it a shot, and describe exactly what part you can't manage or what error you're seeing.

Comment: So are you using Oracle or MySQL?  Oracle (the company) owns MySQL but they are distinct (and very different) RDBMS.

Comment: I am currently using MySQL using the oracle web application

Comment: I've got to be honest Mat I dont even know where to begin, I initially tried to do it the way I learned to join two table but it did not work (COMPLETE NOOB!)

Comment: Could you put what you have so far (probably the table definitions, and some example data) into sqlFiddle.com and attach the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to learn about `JOINS`. I will write part of the `query`. You can complete it with some research from your end.

```
SELECT 
     Activity.Activitydescription,
     Sessions.Dates,
     Sessions.Type,
     Activitysupervisor.Name,
     Activitysupervisor.MobileNumber
FROM Activity 
INNER JOIN Sessions ON Sessions.SessionID = Activity.SessionID
INNER JOIN Activitysupervisor ON Activitysupervisor.SupervisorID = Sessions.SupervisorID
```

> So basically you need to use `JOINS`. Learn more about different types of `JOINS` and complete the `query`.

Comment: Is this ok then?......

SELECT
Individual.IndividualID,
Activity Group.ActivityGroupID, 
Activity.Activitydescription,
Sessions.Dates,
Sessions.Type,
Activitysupervisor.Name,
Activitysupervisor.MobileNumber

FROM Individual

INNER JOIN Activity group ON Activity group.IndividualID = Individual.IndividualID

INNER JOIN Activity ON Actvity.ActivityID = Activity Group.ActivityID

INNER JOIN Sessions ON Sessions.SessionID = Activity.SessionID

INNER JOIN Activity supervisor ON Activitysupervisor.SupervisorID = Sessions.SupervisorID;